# How to get git pull request details using python programming?

Tags: python-3.x, git

I am beginner in python. I have python 3.7 installed.
My requirement is to get list of repositories and pull request details related to each repository using Python. 
Project for which I need all this info is in git repository. Note this is git is azure deveops...not Github.

I tried same in.net as there are multiple Azure Devops Rest API are available for .net I could achieved it, but in case of Python I am not getting any API.

Please help me to learn how to get Git pull requests details using Python.

Comment: Use the host API (GitHub, GitLa, BitBucket..).

Comment: you can refer this [link](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/first-steps-gitpython.html) to get information from git using python

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use requests library ([details](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python)) in Python to post your HTTP query and get JSON responses, for example, you can access Azure Devops REST API for pull request [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) like this,

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.0')
print r.json
```

Alternatively, if your system has cURL installed, you can use it like this,

```py
import os
os.system('curl -u YourUserName:YourPassword https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.0')
```

Using cURL by providing your username and password might be the easier way to solve the authentication issues.

Comment: I have used the first option of requests.get('dev.azure.com{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=5.0') to get all the pull request of particular repository , but i am getting exception bound method Response.json of <Response [203]>>

Comment: Did you replace {organization}, {project} and {repositoryId} with proper values? 
I would recommend use method 2 to avoid authentication problems.  But you need to provide your organization, project, and repositoryId in the HTTP request for it to work properly.

Comment: When I send postman request to https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories, I am getting 401 Unauthorized exception in postman.
The same request is also not working evenafter providing valid credentials in Postman.

Comment: Yes, {organization}, {project} and {repositoryId} is repalced with proper values.

Comment: Please use oauth 2.0 in Postman details [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization/#oauth-20) and fill it with details from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#security) to get access token first.

Comment: Hey @SapnaDeshmukh did you manage to make it work? Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if I have helped you :) Thank you.